# How to provide host functions and make it callable from pallets?

Tags: host-functions

I'm trying to encapsulate some host functions so that I can call them in pallets.

I use sp_runtime_interface::runtime_interface to declare a trait, give the default implementation in the declaration, and then call it in the pallet.

You can see https://github.com/briceyan/substrate-host-function for the demo repo.

```rust
// file: host/src/lib.rs
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

use sp_runtime_interface::runtime_interface;

#[runtime_interface]
pub trait HostApi {
    fn double(n: u32) -> u32 {
        n * 2
    }
}
```

```rust
// file: pallets/template/src/lib.rs
    // snip
    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
        // snip
        #[pallet::call_index(0)]
        #[pallet::weight(10_000 + T::DbWeight::get().writes(1).ref_time())]
        pub fn do_something(origin: OriginFor<T>, something: u32) -> DispatchResult {
            let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            let n: u32 = host_api::double(something);

            // Update storage.
            <Something<T>>::put(n);

            // Emit an event.
            Self::deposit_event(Event::SomethingStored { something: n, who });
            // Return a successful DispatchResultWithPostInfo
            Ok(())
        }
    }
    // snip
```

The code compiles but fails to run due to the following error message:

```
➜  substrate-host-function git:(main) ./target/release/node-template --dev
2023-03-16 13:20:54 Substrate Node
2023-03-16 13:20:54 ✌️  version 4.0.0-dev-33607da1ed4
2023-03-16 13:20:54 ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2023
2023-03-16 13:20:54  Chain specification: Development
2023-03-16 13:20:54   Node name: gratis-sleet-4678
2023-03-16 13:20:54  Role: AUTHORITY
2023-03-16 13:20:54  Database: RocksDb at /var/folders/zz/cbfsklq95h9g3bs85nk4h5780000gp/T/substrateLqIz41/chains/dev/db/full
2023-03-16 13:20:54 ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-100 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)
Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env:ext_host_api_double_version_1'")))
2023-03-16 13:20:55 Cannot create a runtime error=Other("runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env:ext_host_api_double_version_1'")
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a hard thing. You need to add it to the Substrate framework. Otherwise, you can not interact with other chains in the relaychain system.

You can check how people discuss and push this thing.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13031

Comment: Are you suggesting that the only way to add host functions are to add them to substrate itself? Is there no better way (at least for a solo chain) ?

Answer (score 3):

you have to 'register' all host functions in your node as well (see `sc_executor`); for example:

```rust
impl sc_executor::NativeExecutionDispatch for ExecutorDispatch {
    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    type ExtendHostFunctions = frame_benchmarking::benchmarking::HostFunctions;
    #[cfg(not(feature = "runtime-benchmarks"))]
    type ExtendHostFunctions = ();

    ...
```